# Getting .tagName of an element with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys i only wanted to ask how to get the tag name of an element that has a class name, im trying this:

```
function copyElement(){
$('body').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which  == 99){            
        var elementToCopy = $('.highlight').attr('tag');
        alert(elementToCopy);
        var newElement = $(document.createElement(elementToCopy));
    }
});}
```

But im always getting undefined! :( help please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.highlight').prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: This one works perfectly fine thank you :D

Comment: @Cheka - Glad to help you. You can mark it as your answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tag  = this.nodeName.toLowerCase(); // native JS
var tag  = $(this)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase(); // the jquery equiv.
var tag  = $('.SomeClass')[0].nodeName.toLowerCase(); // the jquery equiv. with selector
```

Answer (score 0):

This will go through each tag with that class.

```
$('.highlight').each(function() {
    alert(this.tagName);
});
```